# How to display UITableView with Relationship Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Have looked though many posts, but can't find solution to my situation.

There is entity Days and there is entity Tasks. Each Day can have 0 or many Tasks. I need to show list of tasks for the specific day in a UITableView.

How can I fetch number of rows (Tasks) via relationships for:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    }
```

and then how to format the cell for:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)-> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TodayCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TodayTableViewCell

        let task = //how to get task?

        cell.taskDescription?.text = task.descritpion            

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You dont fetch number of rows, you will need to create your datasource with your filtered results and pass its count to number of rows

Comment: How did you declared the tasks and days variables?

Comment: you should have array that contains the tasks object , then you can select one task this way . let task = tasks[indexPath.row] , number of rows should return tasks.count

Answer (score 0):

- Create a custom struct

  ```
  struct Schedule {
      let date : Date
      var tasks : [Task]
  }
  ```
- Create a data source array

  ```
  var schedules = [Schedule]()
  ```
- Fetch the `Day` entities sorted by day (into an array `days`)
- Map the items to the custom struct if there is one task or more (simple code, most likely your attributes are different)

  ```
  schedules.removeAll()
  for day in days {
      if !day.tasks.isEmpty {
          schedules.append(Schedule(date: day.date, tasks:day.tasks.allObjects as! [Task]))
      }
  }
  tableView.reloadData()
  ```
- In `numberOfSections` return `schedules.count`
- In `numberOfRows...` return `schedules[section].tasks.count`
- In `titleForHeaderInSection` return a string description of `schedules[section].date`
- In `cellForRow...` get a single task

  ```
  let day = schedules[indexPath.section]
  let task = day.tasks[indexPath.row]
  ```